# Is it possible to add any animation to conditionally displayed component in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, components

I want to make a div that will behave like a bootstrap Panel (extend and display additional information when clicked). I have come up with the following solution:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Test.css'
import './Collapsible'
import Collapsible from './Collapsible';

class Test extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
        isHidden: true
    }
}


CollapseClickHandler() {
    const temp = !this.state.isHidden
    this.setState({ isHidden : temp })
}


render() {
    return (
        <div className="hero" onClick={this.CollapseClickHandler.bind(this)}>
            <ul className="collapse">
                    <li>Name: John Doe</li>
                    <li>Year of birth: 1751</li>
                    <li>Height: 123</li>
                    <li>Mass: 124</li>
                    <li>
                        Home: Cardboard box
                    </li>
            </ul>
            {this.state.isHidden ? null : <Collapsible />}
        </div>
    )}
}

export default Test;
```

Is it possible to add some transition to the extension of this element? The logic can be changed if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that using The `@keyframes` rule CSS Animation

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
    show: true,fadeOut: true };

  }
toggle = () =>{
  this.setState({ fadeOut: !this.state.fadeOut })
  if(this.state.show === false){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })
    }, 1000)
  }else{
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })
  }
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <button onClick={this.toggle}>Click</button>
              {this.state.show ? null : <div className={this.state.fadeOut ? 'fadeOut' : 'fade'}><Child /></div>}
      
     
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Child extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="fade">
        <h1>Fade In/Out Using CSS </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.fade {
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */

}
.fadeOut{
    animation: fadeout 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadeout 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadeout 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadeout 2s; /* Opera */
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}




@keyframes fadeout {
    from {
        opacity:1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeout { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:1;
    }
    to {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadeout { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```